# SparkR: compare schemas of sparkdataframes

Tags: r, sparkr

For example, we have 2 two identical sparkdataframes

```
library(SparkR)
df1 <- createDataFrame(iris)
df2 <- createDataFrame(iris)
```

How can we check that they have identical schemas?

```
sdf1 <- schema(df1)
sdf2 <- schema(df2)
print(sdf1)
print(sdf2)
```

We can see that the schemas are the same.

```
StructType
|-name = "Sepal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Sepal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Petal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Petal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Species", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE
StructType
|-name = "Sepal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Sepal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Petal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Petal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Species", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE
```

But

```
identical(sdf1, sdf2)
all.equal(sdf1, sdf2)
```

show that they are not identical.
How can we compare schemas of sparkdataframes?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `SparkR::dtypes` to compare the schema.

```
identical(SparkR::dtypes(df1), SparkR::dtypes(df2))
# TRUE
```